# SQL Query output formatting URL in python

Tags: python, sql, url, formatting

I am new to python. I am writing a script which queries the database for a URL string. Below is my snippet.

```
db.execute('select sitevideobaseurl,videositestring '
          'from site, video '
          'where siteID =1 and site.SiteID=video.VideoSiteID limit 1')
result = db.fetchall()

for row in result:
  videosite= row[0:2]
  print videosite
```

It gives me baseURL from a table and the video site string from another table.
output: `('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={0}', 'uqcSJR_7fOc')`

I wish to format the output by removing the braces, quotes and commas and replace the {0} from baseURL with sitestring: uqcSJR_7fOc. 
something like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqcSJR_7fOc in the final output and wish to write this to a file.

Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

```
db.execute('select sitevideobaseurl,videositestring '
          'from site, video '
          'where siteID =1 and site.SiteID=video.VideoSiteID limit 1')
result = db.fetchall()

for row in result:
  videosite= row[0:2]
  print videosite[0].format(videosite[1])
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: This result worked like wonder. After long time I have come back here to understand how this works just to document it for my knowledge. Can anyone be kind enough to explain how :for row in result:
  videosite= row[0:2]
  print videosite[0].format(videosite[1]) works line by line. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "replace" command in either Sql or Python.

```
str_url = str_url.replace('[','')
str_url = str_url.replace(']','')
str_url = str_url.replace('?','')
```

Something like this in Python which is the easier of the two to do.

Repeat for as many characters as you want to chop out

My str_url is your "videosite".